# How can I find games based on Caesar's campaigns in Gaul and Britannia?

Tags: untagged

I like [Caesar's Gallic War](http://www.worthingtongames.com/detailCG.html) by Worthington games.

How can I locate similarly themed games that focus on Caesar's campaigns in Gaul and Britannia?

Comment: Folks, if you want to discuss the closing further please open a question on [meta](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [Meta question opened.](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/541/1140)

Comment: I've edited and reopened this question.  Pietro, it would be great if you could edit in specifically what attracted you to this theme and the aspects of Caesar's Gallic War that appeals to you.

Answer (score 6):

One great way to find similarly themed games is to consult the GeekLists on [BoardGameGeek](http://http:/www.boardgamegeek.com).

1. Find [your game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/43245/caesars-gallic-war) on Boardgamegeek
2. Scroll to the bottom, look for the "GeekList" section
3. Check out GeekLists that sound interesting.

For Caesar's Gallic War, I found this GeekList, [Bellum Gallicum (58-51 BC) - Caesar Against the Gauls](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/13869/item/1055456) which appears to be a well curated list of 20 games dealing with Caesar and the Gauls.